# How do I grant a SELECT permission to an individual user who's part of a large group that is explicitly denied?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, permissions, security

I have a table SuperSecretData which is currently setup to deny SELECT to everyone in the company by the standard Active Directory account "Domain Users". But a couple of specific individual users do need to be able to SELECT from it.
What's the proper way to achieve this?

[image: Table Properties - Permissions]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DENY overrides GRANT, and an inherited DENY even overrides a direct GRANT.  And a DENY at the schema or database level overrides a GRANT at the object level.

So you won't be able to directly override the DENY.

You can create a view, synonym, or stored procedure owned by the same user as SuperSecretData and grant them access to that.

> is there a better way to GRANT SELECT to almost all entities on my SQL server to "Domain Users" except for a couple of tables that I'd only want some specific users to have SELECT permissions on?

Yes.  Never use the built-in roles, and always use schema-level grants.  Then you can create separate schemas for additional security.  Eg

```
grant select on schema::dbo to ...
```

instead of a built-in role

```
alter role db_datareader add . . .
```

or a database-level grant

```
grant select to ...
```

Comment: Yea I figured I might be a little out of luck going this route. But assuming I created a new view as you mentioned, wouldn't that bring me back to square one where anyone would be able to SELECT from it until I explicitly denied that permission? 

Also, if I structured our entities a little bit different such that SuperSecretData belonged to a schema called KeepOutPlebs, would I be able to explicitly DENY access to the KeepOutPlebs schema to "Domain Users" but then GRANT SELECT permissions to individual users on the table SuperSecretData?

Comment: Well no one can select from the view or table without permissions.  You just need to ensure that no one has a global SELECT permission in the database.  An alternate route would be to encrypt the data in the table with a symmetric key, and write a view that reads the data with DECRYPTBYKEYAUTOASYMKEY 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/decryptbykeyautoasymkey-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017  That way a database-level SELECT permission wouldn't grant access to the data.

Comment: Sorry yes, I should've specified more clearly, "Domain Users" is globally granted SELECT on most databases on our SQL server (when mapping the databases at the Server - Logins level).
Given that being the case, wouldn't this view that decrypts the table also be accessible to "Domain Users"?

Comment: They could SELECT from the view, but not OPEN the SYMMETRIC KEY.  That's a separate permission.

Comment: Gotcha, ok thanks, that's helpful and might be the solution I end up using in this case.
But if I didn't want to go the route of creating encryption and custom entities to give data access to specific users, starting fresh, is there a better way to GRANT SELECT to almost all entities on my SQL server to "Domain Users" except for a couple of tables that I'd only want some specific users to have SELECT permissions on? (I know I can script it out easily with dynamic SQL, but I wonder if there's just a better way to structure it that I'm not thinking of.)

Comment: See update in answer.